# Predict daily value with LSTM which has hourly timeseries as input

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a single layer LSTM that is coded as follows:

```
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=64,
                            input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1,  activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
  loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001),
  metrics=['acc']
)
```

The input to my LSTM is a hourly timeseries. I want to predict values at a daily level based on the hourly series. 
Currently what I do is generate hourly predictions and then take the first prediction as the prediction for each day. However I wanted to know if there is a way to generate the same prediction at a daily level. 
Thank you!

Comment: What kind of thing are you trying to predict? Does your hourly data consist of 24 hours that you somehow want to assign a meaningful score to, or do you have many more hours leading up to a single day you want to predict? Is the daily value you want to predict the sum of hourly (predicted) values, or the mean, or max, or something else entirely?

Comment: Hi, It is a classification problem so each hourly label is a 1 or 0, which is constant over a day. I want to predict whether the next day will be 1 or 0 depending on previous inputs.

Comment: In that case you could just use the hourly data as input, and try to predict a single value for the next day. If you would use, say, the previous two days as input you'd have 48 hours of input for a single day value as target.

Comment: how would I predict a single value for the next day?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options as my opinion.

1. Train the model using daily based training data set. When filtering out what the most suitable datapoint for the day is, you can use the datapoint having the greatest number of repeatitions ( mode ) or the mean.
2. Take the outputs hourly based but forecasting 24 outputs for the next 24 hours and get the mean or mode of those 24 as the prediction for the day.

The best way is probably second one. It would be much accurate.

Answer (score 1):

One option is you can also give an argument called `batch_input_shape` instead of `input_shape`. The difference is now you have to give a fixed batch size and your input array shape will look like `(24, X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])`.

You also have an option to set another argument `return_sequences`. This argument tells whether to return the output at **each time step** instead of the **final time step**. As we set the `return_sequences` to `True`, the output shape becomes a 3D array, instead of a 2D array.

```py
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=64,
                            batch_input_shape=(24, X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1,  activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
  loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001),
  metrics=['acc']
)
```